# Firebase and Nuxt3: How to detach onSnapshot listener?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs3

I am using the Firestore `onSnapshot` listener in a component in my Nuxt3 app. I am wondering how to detach the listener when the component is unMounted. How do I successfully detach the listener? I assume I could call the `unsubscribe` listener in the `onUnMounted` hook?

I have set up the listener in an `onMounted()` and detached hook like so:

```
<script setup>
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'
import {
  onSnapshot,
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs
} from 'firebase/firestore'

const userStore = useUserStore()
const loading = ref(false)
const userPosts = reactive([])
const unsubscribe = ref(null)

onMounted(async () => {
  const { firestore } = useFirebase()
  const userPostsRef = collection(firestore, 'posts')
  const q = query(userPostsRef, where('uid', '==', userStore.userProfile.uid))
  unsubscribe.value = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        console.log('added', change.doc.data())
        userPosts.push(change.doc.data())
      }
      if (change.type === 'modified') {
        console.log('modified', change.doc.data())
        userPosts.splice(
          userPosts.findIndex((post) => post.id === change.doc.id),
          1,
          change.doc.data()
        )
      }
      if (change.type === 'removed') {
        console.log('removed', change.doc.data())
        userPosts.splice(
          userPosts.findIndex((post) => post.id === change.doc.id),
          1
        )
      }
    })
  })
  loading.value = false
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  unsubscribe.value //<-----is this the correct way to detach it?
})
```

**Edit:** I just confirmed that the above method does not remove the listener because every time I navigate away from the page, I get the console logs of ('added', 'modified', etc). SO, I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsubscribe` is a function so you'll have to call it as shown below:

```
onUnmounted(() => {
  // call only when unsubscribe is not null
  unsubscribe.value && unsubscribe.value()

  // or use optional chaining
  unsubscribe.value?.();
})
```